# Java: parsing and writing xml files

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I need to parse a xml document with Java and output another xml document.

More specifically, I have a list of items in the original xml file and I need to group them, averaging the values, and output few averaged items.

should I use any java library for that ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing xml and writing to another XML document is best done with JDOM. However, grouping and averaging is gonna be painful with JDOM.

You could also use JAXB to create POJOs from the xml, then do your averaging and grouping on the POJO, and marshall it afterwards with JAXB back to XML.

If the target XML has a different schema then the source XML, and conversion between the POJOs is required, use [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: it sounds complicated, or it just sounds ? I will give a look now, what I need is to aggregate terms of specific fields, and averaging numeric values for other fields. Than, replace the original items with the new one (with aggregated terms and averages).

Comment: JAXB is really simple, and I would prefer POJOs to do your aggregating and averaging instead of using JDOM. Downside is, if your XML structure is complicated, you end up with a lot of POJOs. Take a look at [this](http://confusion.tweakblogs.net/blog/1344/ultrashort-jaxb-tutorial.html) to get an idea about how JAXB works.

Comment: The xml structure is very simple, just a list of xml elements with 6 children each. So you vote for POJO because of the averaging.

Comment: I would go with POJOs then. Also, if I can throw in another API, use XMLUnit for your unit test. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to make use of a library. Doing it without a library means you will have to code for parsing and creating your xml the hard way. I suggest you use [JDom](http://www.jdom.org/). Here is a list of Java XMl library: http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-parsers

Comment: I do not believe that list is currently being maintained.  It is missing several options, and some parsers listed have not produced new versions in years.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use DOM or SAX to parse an XML file. DOM allows you to navigate to each xml item, while SAX is based on events the parser emits while parsing the file. DOM is usually easier to work with, however since it loads the whole xml file into memory it won't work for large files, in which case you're better off using SAX. You can find both parsers in the javax.xml.parsers package.
You can find some examples for both parsers here http://java.sun.com/developer/codesamples/xml.html

Comment: Is DOM = JDOM ? I also have another question: since I'm average across items, and I can only find out them progressively, by parsing the XML file, I was wondering if I should keep in memory all new averaged items until when I output them to the new xml file or not

Comment: @Patrick JDOM is a different project which provides an API similar to DOM for parsing XML files. They say in their web site that their API is simpler to use than the DOM Java API but I've never used it so I don't have an opinion. I guess keeping the items in memory is the simpler solution if you don't have many items. If space is a constraint you would probably have to keep a reference or something allowing you to find the necessary items again after the avaraging part is done.

Comment: @Patrick:  DOM is the W3C standard and there are multiple implementations of it:  Xerces, Oracle XDK, etc.  JDOM is its own project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DOM or SAX parsers for parsing XML documents using Java.

The [Java API for XML Processing(JAXP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing) , is one of the Java XML programming APIs. It provides the capability of validating and parsing XML documents.

But, it would be better if you follow these links before deciding the right approach.

- [XML Parsers: DOM and SAX Put to the Test](http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/16922/1954)
- [XMLParsers](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~epontell/courses/XML/material/xmlparsers.html)

Confused about DOM or SAX ?
Visit here :  [Should I use DOM or SAX](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=28)

Also, recommended reading [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

Comment: The JAXB article you link to is for version 1.  For information on JAXB 2 check out:  http://jaxb.java.net/, http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php, and http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Comment: Check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html